# Can we find out the direction of $\textbf{A}$ from $\nabla\times\textbf{A}$?

Tags: gauge-theory, differentiation, vector-fields

Given a vector field of the form $\textbf{B}=\nabla\times\textbf{A}$, can we uniquely find out the direction of $\textbf{A}$?

Comment: No. Consider that $\nabla \times \nabla f = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If you find any specific $\mathbf A_0$ such that $\nabla \times \mathbf A_0$ matches your given $\mathbf B$, then adding *any* constant vector to $\mathbf A$ will result in an equally valid vector potential. Even more strongly, since the curl of every gradient vanishes, adding a gradient to $\mathbf A_0$ will also result in an equally valid vector potential.

This is known as the [gauge freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#Gauge_freedom) of classical electrodynamics and it's discussed in detail in any textbook that talks about the vector potential.

Comment: I'm sorry for the poor notation. $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ are arbitrary vectors. Not the vector potential and the magnetic field.  $\textbf{A}$ 
 is an arbitrary vector. @EmilioPisanty

Comment: That's ultimately irrelevant, and no, $\mathbf B$ cannot be arbitrary - your condition forces it to be divergenceless, so it can happily be interpreted as a magnetic field even if that wasn't your original intention. The core of the answer stands and, since your question can be directly mapped into EM even despite your protestations, the language holds as well.

Comment: ... but I'm happy to downvote based on the misleading language that you then tried to walk back on, coupled to the poor research effort.